# Member specialization of alias declaration in different namespaces

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, clang++

I just encountered a strange difference in behavior between clang and gcc where I wanted to compile code which looks similar to the following:

```cpp
namespace n1 {
  template <class T1, class T2>
  struct MyTemplate {
    struct Inner {};
  };
}

using namespace n1;
namespace n2 {
  using MyClass = MyTemplate<int, int>;
}

namespace n1 {
  using n2::MyClass;
  template<> struct MyClass::Inner {
    int member;
  };

  MyClass::Inner inner{0};
}
```

Clang happily compiles this:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 -c -o alias_specialization.o alias_specialization.cc
```

but gcc throws the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -c -o alias_specialization.o alias_specialization.cc

alias_specialization:15:30: error: declaration of ‘struct n1::MyTemplate<int, int>::Inner’ in namespace ‘n1’ which does not enclose ‘using MyClass = struct n1::MyTemplate<int, int>’
   template<> struct MyClass::Inner {
```

I know I can just write the full name of the original type (`MyTemplate<int, int>`) instead of `MyClass` in line 15.
But I'm simply wondering which of the two compilers is "right".
The exact compilers in use are:

```
$ clang++ --version
clang version 4.0.0

$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20170306
```

Comment: I don't know whether GCC is right, but note that you can trick if you "import" MyClass in n1 by writing `using MyClass = n2::MyClass;` instead of `using n2::MyClass;` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: <del>GCC</del> Clang is right (as @suluke pointed out, using the findings below).

I found the following passages in the C++14 standard, but I am sure the same applies to C++11:

### Part I: Specialization & Instantiation of Templates

#### `inline namespace` (§7.3.1 cl. 8):

> Members of an inline namespace can be used in most respects as though they were members of the enclosing namespace. Specifically, the inline namespace and its enclosing namespace are both added to the set of associated namespaces used in argument-dependent lookup (3.4.2) whenever one of them is, and a using- directive (7.3.4) that names the inline namespace is implicitly inserted into the enclosing namespace as for an unnamed namespace (7.3.1.1). Furthermore, each member of the inline namespace can subsequently be partially specialized (14.5.5), explicitly instantiated (14.7.2), or **explicitly specialized (14.7.3)** as though it were a member of the enclosing namespace. Finally, looking up a name in the enclosing namespace via explicit qualification (3.4.3.2) will include members of the inline namespace brought in by the using-directive even if there are declarations of that name in the enclosing namespace.

#### Explicit instantiation (§ 14.7.2 cl. 3)

> If the explicit instantiation is for a class or member class, the elaborated-type-specifier in the declaration shall include a simple-template-id. If the explicit instantiation is for a function or member function, the unqualified- id in the declaration shall be either a template-id or, where all template arguments can be deduced, a template-name or operator-function-id. [Note: The declaration may declare a qualified-id, in which case the unqualified-id of the qualified-id must be a template-id. —end note] If the explicit instantiation is for a member function, a member class or a static data member of a class template specialization, the name of the class template specialization in the qualified-id for the member name shall be a simple-template-id. If the explicit instantiation is for a variable, the unqualified-id in the declaration shall be a template-id. **An explicit instantiation shall appear in an enclosing namespace of its template. If the name declared in the explicit instantiation is an unqualified name, the explicit instantiation shall appear in the namespace where its template is declared or, if that namespace is inline (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set.**

#### Explicit instantiation (§ 14.7.2 cl. 6)

> An explicit instantiation of a class, function template, or variable template specialization is placed in the namespace in which the template is defined. An explicit instantiation for a member of a class template is placed in the namespace where the enclosing class template is defined. An explicit instantiation for a member template is placed in the namespace where the enclosing class or class template is defined. [ Example:

```
namespace N {
    template<class T> class Y { void mf() { } };
  }
  template class Y<int>;  // error: class template Y not visible 
                          // in the global namespace

  using N::Y;
  template class Y<int>; // error: explicit instantiation outside of the 
                         // namespace of the template


  template class N::Y<char*>;  // OK: explicit instantiation in namespace N
  template void N::Y<double>::mf();  // OK: explicit instantiation
                                     // in namespace N
```

> — end example ]

### Part II: Typedef, Aliasing

#### What is typedef or an alias?

§7.1.3 cl. 1 states:

> [...]
>   A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name. Within the scope of its declaration, a typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and names the type associated with the identifier in the way described in Clause 8. **A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type. A typedef-name does not introduce a new type the way a class declaration (9.1) or enum declaration does.**

§7.1.3 cl. 2 states:

> A typedef-name can also be introduced by an **alias-declaration**. The identifier following the using keyword becomes a typedef-name and the optional attribute-specifier-seq following the identifier appertains to that typedef-name. **It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier. In particular, it does not define a new type** and it shall not appear in the type-id.

### Part III: Testing Your Case

Following your logic the following code should compile and produce 2 different types. I tested it with Clang, which is the compiler in question. Clang produces the same type as standard it requires.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace n1 {
  template <class T1, class T2>
  struct MyTemplate {
    struct Inner {};
  };
}

using namespace n1;
namespace n2 {
  using MyClass = MyTemplate<int, int>;
}

namespace n3 {
  using MyClass = MyTemplate<int, int>;
}

namespace n1 {
  using n2::MyClass;
  template<> struct MyClass::Inner {
    int member;
  };

  MyClass::Inner inner{0};
}

namespace n4{
  using n3::MyClass;

  MyClass::Inner inner{0};
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  cout << typeid(n1::inner).name() << endl;
  cout << typeid(n4::inner).name() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

```
c++ -std=c++14 typedef-typeid.cpp -O3 -o compiled.bin
```

OR

```
c++ -std=c++11 typedef-typeid.cpp -O3 -o compiled.bin
```

**Output in both cases**

```
N2n110MyTemplateIiiE5InnerE
N2n110MyTemplateIiiE5InnerE
```

As it turns out that in this context `typedef` and `using` are equivalent, we can use `typedef` instead of `using`.

**§7.3.3 cl. 1** points this out:

> [...] If a using-declaration names a constructor (3.4.3.1), it implicitly declares a set of constructors in the class in which the using-declaration appears (12.9); **otherwise the name specified in a using-declaration is a synonym for a set of declarations in another namespace or class**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace n1 {
  template <class T1, class T2>
  struct MyTemplate {
    struct Inner {};
  };
}

using namespace n1;
namespace n2 {
  typedef MyTemplate<int, int> MyClass;
}


namespace n1 {
  typedef n2::MyClass MyClass;

  template<> struct MyClass::Inner {
    int member;
  };

  MyClass::Inner inner{0};
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  cout << typeid(n1::inner).name() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And GCC perfectly compiles the example, without blaming anything.

In addition it'd be interesting to find out how the **transitiveness** with `using` declaration works with GCC.

Here is the modified example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

namespace n1 {
  template <class T1, class T2>
  struct MyTemplate {
    struct Inner {};
  };
}


using namespace n1;
namespace n2 {
  using MyClass = MyTemplate<int, int>;

}

namespace n3
{
  using n2::MyClass;
}


namespace n1 {
  typedef n3::MyClass MyClass;

  template<> struct MyClass::Inner {
    int member;
  };

  MyClass::Inner inner{0};
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  cout << typeid(n1::inner).name() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And again both Clang and GCC happily compile it.

Comment: This is of course a complicated topic, so excuse me if I overlooked something. But I thought that what makes my example a bit special is the type alias `MyClass` which somewhat obscurs the namespace in which `MyClass::Inner` is defined. So my understanding was that gcc treats the type alias as if it were a `#define` whereas clang sees it as a new type. I don't see any reference to type aliases in your answer, so I think this part is still missing. Still a huge thank you for the time you spent on looking into the standard!

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing it out. I rewrote my answer to be more structured and addressed missing parts with additional tests.

Comment: Ok, I accepted your answer, but now I think it's wrong :D If we take
> `An explicit instantiation shall appear in an enclosing namespace`
and
> `A typedef-name is thus a synonym for another type`
and
> `[using] has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the typedef specifier`
then I believe clang is right and gcc is wrong. 
`template<> struct MyClass::Inner` should be exactly the same to the compiler as `template<> struct MyTemplate<int, int>::Inner`, right? As the comment by @tux3 suggests, the `using` declaration ("import") might be the problem here...

Comment: Now I think so too. Actually, what I've overseen is that you specialize the template in `n1` namespace. Than in IMO it is correct and gcc is wrong. I replaced `using` with `typedef` and it worked just fine. See my edits.

Comment: If you just change the first line of your answer I can mark it as the accepted answer again :) What I meant when I said the "import" might be the problem is the usage of `using n2::Myclass` as opposed to `using MyClass = n2::Myclass` in line 14. Although I really don't think this should matter (but feel free to look into the standard again ;) ). Let's just agree that gcc is wrong here

Comment: I just looked it up and adopted the answer with an additional cite from §7.3.3 and one more example, which shows how wrong GCC is :)